# How to store file images into mysql (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I tried to upload file images into mysql using Codeigniter

This is likely my upload view:

```
<label>Upload File</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images">
</div>
```

I've done with image name, description, etc.

I tried to save it into database, just like normal input form.

The result, column "images" cannot be null. I have set column "images" with varbinary(3000)

Am I doing it wrong?

EDITED:

My Controller:

```
public function save(){
    $this->gallery_model->save_foto();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','FOTO BERHASIL DI UPLOAD');
    redirect(base_url('gallery'));
}
```

My Model

```
<?php
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model {
      public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
      }

  public function save_foto(){
    $data['id']            = date('U');
    $data['nm_foto']       = $this->input->post('nm_foto');
    $data['username']      = $this->input->post('username');
    $data['tanggal']       = date('j F Y');
    $data['images']        = $this->input->post('images');
    $data['deskripsi']     = $this->input->post('deskripsi');
    $this->db->insert( 'gallery', $data );
  }
}
```

Comment: saving images into database is not a good idea..try uploading images on server and then save filepath into database

Comment: could you please share your controller and model code also ?

Comment: image upload is just like the other file uploads.Only thing u can do is give the allowed extensions as .jpeg,.jpg,.png,etc and save the path in database

Comment: you will not get input type file's data into post method

Comment: I failed to do upload with Codeigniter ways. Always met Upload Path error things. So I tried this. I can save it to my folder instead with my teachers code, but you know, I tried to make an art website, so it would need database I think?

Comment: Can you show the code which you have tried to upload file to folder

Comment: @Shibon I answered it in asnwer section. Check mine.

Comment: Hey refer this link you can see how to upload file ...

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

@Hermes Djohar -->U have not show the code which you tried to upload file....till you code is to save data to database

Comment: @Shibon Like I said, I'm getting tired with uploading with CI ways, it just simply doesn't work. I'm tired of getting error "Upload Path not valid", I tried people's answer like "this->initialize->config", All I got was "SERVER ERROR 500"

I'm done uploading to folders without CI ways, at least with my teachers code

Answer (score 0):

### You can't directly upload image into database , Insert image path

For upload image form form add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in form .

For more help regarding image upload in codeigniter

[Codeigniter Image Upload](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can store images but its not advisable.

The "correct" way to do it is to store the files somewhere on your server and store the URI in the database.

The problem is that images can be quite large, this can result in a big load on your database which is unnecessary. When you work on a larger scale project you may have multiple database that need to be synchronised, when you database is larger then it need to be you unnecessary slow down your network.

If you still want the image stored in the datebase, you can store it as an `BLOB` type. See the [MySQL documenation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)

You can insert it then with the following example code

```
$data['image'] = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone met an error and getting tired just like me, here's the simple way and codes you can upload [images] into your assets folder

In Controller

```
public function upd_gallery(){
    $file = $this->input->post('img_name').".jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], './wheretosave/etc/etc'.$file);
    redirect( base_url().'gallery');
}
```

Set application -> config -> routes

```
$route['gallery/upload2'] = 'gallery/upd_gallery';
```

Put this to your view

```
<?php
    $ff = './where-to-save/etc/'.$this->input->post('img_name').'.jpg';
?>
     <form  action="<?= base_url()?>gallery/upload2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="img_name" required="required">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-common" value="Update"> Upload</button>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Of course, this way is very simple. You just have to name your image and save it

Answer (score 0):

Saving image in database is NOT good practice. You can use following code to store files on your server's file system.

```
$userfile= $this->input->post('userfile'); //gets image name only

if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != '') { //to check if you've selected any file 
    $path = './path/to/folder';
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';

    if (!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) 
    die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        return "UPLOAD ERROR ! " . $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    else {
        $filepath = $this->upload->data();
        $doc_path = $filepath['file_name'];
        return $doc_path;
    }

}
```